# How to render an image on a php page by dynamically taking the path returned on the same page from MySQL database

Tags: php, html

So i want my page to show the image whose path I am getting from the mysql database and displaying on the same screen. This is my code, I have tried everything, please let  me know where I'm going wrong.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($return_data)) {

        echo "ID:".$row['demo_id']."<br>";
        echo "Name: ".$row['demo_name']."<br>";
        echo "Version: ".$row['demo_version']."<br>";
        echo "Details: ".$row['demo_details']."<br>";
        echo "File Link: ".$row['file']."<br>";
        $new = $row['file'];
        echo '<img src = \"$new\"/>';
    }

    mysqli_free_result($return_data);
    echo "Data retrieved successfully!"."<br>";
    ?>

    <img src = "<?php echo $new?>">
```

echo "File Link: " returns me the whole path of the uploaded file.

How do I render the image at that path in the same page?

neither of the image tags are working. Thanks in advance!

edit

File Link: C:/Apache24/htdocs/demo_webpages_project/neweruploads/footer.jpg

this is the path I get as an output.

Basically this is the folder where I have uploaded the image from another php file

```
<?php

        //this module is used to temporarily store the uploaded file to the server
        $target_dir = "random/"; //we randomly assign a value to the upload target directory
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image_file"]["name"]); /*here ["name"] is the original name of the file before it was updated 
                                                                              target file is assigned this name by appending it to the $targer_dir
                                                                              now target_file is the uploaded file name along with the path*/
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);/*this returns various kind of info about the path for eg Directory, Basename
                                                                   in our case it returns extension of the file*/


        //this sub module is to check whether the file is really an image file
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) { //isset is used to confirm whether the value has actually being submitted 
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"]);/*here ["tmp_name"] is the location of temporary file on server
                                                                    getimagesize confirms image format by returning dimensions etc*/
            if($check !== false) {
                echo "A file is of an image format<br>";
            }
            else {
                echo "The file is not an image!<br>";
            }
        }


        //Test module to upload files to a destination directory and check whether they have been uploaded or not
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['image_file']['error']==0) { /*code to check two things: 1. whether the file exists in the                                                                                                   temp memory 2. whether the file has any error*/
            $path = 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\demo_webpages_project\neweruploads\\' . $_FILES['image_file']['name']; /*this sets the destination directory(along with expected file                                                                                               name)*/
            if (!file_exists($path)) {  //if the file does not exists at that path
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) { //use the php file move function to move it
                    echo "The file was uploaded successfully."; //success
                } 
                else {
                    echo "The file was not uploaded successfully."; //failure
                }
            } 
            else {
                echo "File already exists. Please upload another file."; //detects existence of file with exact same name
            }
        } 
        else {
            echo "The file was not uploaded successfully."; //if any problem with original uploading
            echo "(Error Code:" . $_FILES['image_file']['error'] . ")";
        }

    ?>
```

Does this help?

edit 2

http://localhost:8080/demo_webpages_project/download.php?project_name=footer&version=&submit=Search

this is my local directory path.

the solution you provided is allowing me to read images which are in the demo_webpages_project folder pointing directly there), not to neweruploads folder

Comment: Try this `echo "<img src='".$new."' />";`

Comment: `whole path`? As in `/home/sites/example.com/html/uploads/kittens.jpg`? That'll never work. You have to output a URL, not a filesystem path. you'd need want `<img src="/uploads/kittens.jpg">`

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I have added the edit, please check.

Comment: @MarcB I see! Any way could extract the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If your uploaded files are stored in the `neweruploads` subdirectory, then replace this code:

```
$new = $row['file'];
echo '<img src = \"$new\"/>';
```

By this one :

```
$new = basename( $row['file'] ); // GET FILE NAME ONLY, GET RID OF PATH.
echo '<img src = \"neweruploads/$new\"/>'; // FILENAME WITH UPLOAD PATH.
                         ▲
```

Comment: @siddparkar, you can also try `echo '<img src = \"/neweruploads/$new\"/>';` (with a slash just before "neweruploads").

Comment: Sadly neither is this working. It only picks up the image file from the root directory.

Comment: even this doesn't take me to the neweruploads page echo '<img src = \"/demo_webpages_project/neweruploads/$new\"/>';

Comment: @siddparkar, the images are being uploaded, you just need to find the proper URL path of the directory where the images are stored. Can you write the localhost URL of that directory, for example, `http://localhost/neweruploads`?

Comment: Hi I used .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and it works now, as the localhost path is correctly set. But now I have run into bigger trouble regarding friendly URL. Making another thread for the same.

Comment: Hi I'd be grateful if you could guide about this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623536/make-a-friendly-url-with-2-parameters-on-php-with-apache