# Make a friendly URL with 2 parameters on PHP with Apache

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, seo

So I am in a bit of a soup here.

I need to make a friendly URL.

This is the URL where I enter the search values project_name and version

localhost:8080/demo_webpages_project/retrieval.html

This is where it takes me to on submitting the values

localhost:8080/demo_webpages_project/download.php?project_name=QT&version=3.1.2

I want the URL in the following form

localhost:8080/demo_webpages_project/download/QT/3.1.2

I tried doing this using .htaccess but not really finding a solution

The following is the code for the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Turn the engine on
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#attempt1
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ download.php?project_name=$1&version=$1
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ download.php?version=$1

#attempt2
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ download.php?project_name=$1&version=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ download.php?version=$1

</IfModule>
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out with this. This is the first time I am working on something on this and am lost.

Thanks

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php

Comment: http://edinteractive.co.uk/friendly-url-using-php-and-htaccess/

Comment: @Eli I tried using all the methods specified, nowhere could I find friendly URL successfully manipulated for two parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this .htaccess inside `/demo_webpages_project/`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo_webpages_project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ download.php?project_name=$1&version=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked! I was missing the RewriteBase part!

Comment: Done. If its not too much trouble, could you please tell how the regex worked? Thanks!

Comment: `[^/]+` is a negated character class. It matches 1 or more of any character except `/`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140220075845/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls), you want a mod_rewrite (placed in an .htaccess file) rule that looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/news/([0-9]+)\.html /news.php?news_id=$1
```

And this maps requests from

```
/news.php?news_id=63
```

to

```
/news/63.html
```

Another possibility is doing it with forcetype, which forces anything down a particular path to use php to eval the content. So, in your .htaccess file, put the following:

```
<Files news>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

And then the index.php can take action based on the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] variable:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
    // outputs '/63.html'
?>
```

Comment: Hello I tried the following too #3
    #RewriteRule /download.php/(.*)$ /download.php/download.php?project_name=$1&version=$2

    #4
 RewriteRule ^demo_webpages_project/download.php/([a-z_]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+)$ /demo_webpages_project/download.php?project_name=$1&version=$2

Comment: Neither work. I am getting these errors Notice: Undefined index: project_name in C:\Apache24\htdocs\demo_webpages_project\download.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: version in C:\Apache24\htdocs\demo_webpages_project\download.php on line 39